# Syntax confusion

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do the following.

```
$a = "Service1","EventLog","Service2"          
gwmi -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$a[1]'" | select Name,State
```

This does not result in any output. However, when I change `$a[1]` to `$($a[1])` it does work. Why do I have to make this syntax change? The way I see it, `$a[1]` is between quotation marks?

EDIT: Also, why can I `$($a[1])` to `$($a[$_])` I get an error that the array index evaluated to null. I am confused to say the least...

Comment: I would guess that you are accessing the array of the char array pointers but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to call the `gwmi` command for each keyword you specify in the `$a` array. Try this approach:

```
$a = "Service1","EventLog","Service2"          
$a | %{ gwmi -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$_'" } | select Name,State
```

Not that we are piping `$a` to a `foreach-object` ( the `%{ .. }` part) and call the `gwmi` within it. Each element of the array is available inside the block now as `$_`

In your earlier case, `$($a[$_])` would definitely give the error you got as in that context the special `$_` variable is null, and index for an array cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

This is just because in `"Name='$a[1]'"` the part `$a` is evaluated first. It gives :

```
Name='Service1 EventLog Service2[1]'
```

For $_ be carefull it gives the curent value in `foreach-object` Cmdlet. So in your case it should be `$null`.

Sorry, I was not clear enough. In your case "Name='$a[$_]'" has no sens in you case you can try :

```
$a | foreach-object  {gwmi -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$_'" | select Name,State
```

Comment: So you are saying I should change it to $($a[$null])? Because that still gives the same error. Thanks for the first part of the answer, that makes alot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid making multiple calls to `gwmi`, you can concatenate your services into a single filter. Generally I try to do as much filtering in the original cmdlet (IIRC, this is considered a best practice), instead of shuffling more than I need through the pipeline (filter as close to the source as possible). This becomes more important as you start running WMI (and other) queries against multiple remote systems.

Sloppy, but works:

```
$a = "Service1","EventLog","Service2";
$filter = "";
$a|foreach-object {$filter += "name='$_' or ";};
$filter = $filter.substring(0,$filter.Length - 3);
gwmi -Class Win32_Service -Filter $filter | select Name,State
```

You can also pass an array right into `get-service` but you'll want to handle the exceptions thrown when a service isn't found by one or more of the names passed in:

```
$a = "Service1","EventLog","Service2";
get-service -Include $a|select name,state;
```